# oAuth 2.0 Google API asp.net from access_token

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to integrate google drive in my asp.net app.
I use google file picker (after authentication) on client side for pick a file id.
Then i have two variable :

- File ID
- access_token

I'would download this file directly to my server from google drive.

My idea is send this two variable to my server (via ajax) and then use google drive library for download the file data and store it to my server.

My question is how can i authenticate the google service on my server with access_token variable without refresh_token ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"how can i authenticate..."
You don't need to authenticate. Once you have an access token, you simply include that in an "Authentication: bearer" header to the http request to drive.